# Python list to pil image

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-imaging-library

Just really quick:
I need to convert a python list into a pillow image.

The list might look something like this:

```
[[(1,1,1,255),(2,2,2,255),(3,3,3,255)],

 [(1,1,1,255),(2,2,2,255),(3,3,3,255)],

 [(1,1,1,255),(2,2,2,255),(3,3,3,255)]]
```

Basicly a 2D array with pixels encoded as (R,G,B,Alpha)

I also have a variable called "size" which is the resulting image size, for example [1000,2000] (doesn't match with the example list which would just be [3,3] ofc.)

I know it's a total noob question. But how do I get this list into a Pillow RGBA Image without using slow loops?

Comment: convert it to a numpy ndarray and use Image.frombuffer (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombuffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert that to numpy array and then can construct the image from the numpy array:

```
import  numpy as np
from PIL import Image

a = [[(1,1,1,255),(2,2,2,255),(3,3,3,255)],
    [(1,1,1,255),(2,2,2,255),(3,3,3,255)],
    [(1,1,1,255),(2,2,2,255),(3,3,3,255)]]
x = np.asarray(a, dtype=np.uint8)
Image.fromarray(x)
>>> <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=3x3 at 0x7F8C4096E640>
```

Comment: Tried that. But it produced an error due to another part in the code which occured randomly. This works of course :) Thank you